# Illustrator CMYk to Pantone solid-coated color

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator

Is it possible to make a script that will convert all CMYK colors to Pantone solid-coated color? I try to use the Recolor-Artwork option But it's not converting all layers. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: The problem is there is no exact matching between CMYK colors and Panton colors. Usually you have several Pantone samples that look relatively similar with a given CMYK color. And you have to chose which of these samples fits better. To understand how tricky the task you can try this online tool: https://www.ginifab.com/feeds/pms/cmyk_to_pantone.php

Answer (score 0):

Basically the task has no strict solution.

Let's take the random CMYK color 38,77,100,0 for example... Oops:

[image]

https://www.ginifab.com/feeds/pms/cmyk_to_pantone.php: